# Is there a built-in tool to generate "create table with index" script in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, create-table

I'd like to re-create an empty table based on existing one in my SQL Server  2012, the table is optimized with lot of indices, however I can't find any options for re-building those indices. The menu option `Script Table as --> DROP And CREATE To` will only create table structure itself.

Is there a way to solve my problem ? It's hard for me to build those indices manually.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

along with Table Structure want Indexes

Then

GO TO ->

```
SQLSERVER --> Tools --> Options
-->
SQL Server Object Explorer-->Scripting/Script Indexes
```

OR

GO TO -- > Generate Scripts --> It will give Table Script with Indexes

```
-- set to "True"
```